# is it possible execute a parallel process inside a Azure durable function?

Tags: c#, azure, parallel-processing, azure-functions

I am new in Azure durable function. and I am wondering if it is possible to run a parallel process inside an azure function. I am not referred to use an azure function that run in parallel by call it in a loop. I refer to use a method that is inside or part of an Azure function and run it in parallel as we run in the normal C# code.
Thanks

Comment: Can you describe your use case better?  I'm pretty sure the answer to your question is _"Yes"_, but I'm not sure what the question is.

Comment: Suppose that inside an Activity durable function you have a method that you want to call in parallel (with a whenAll for example). then the question is: Is it OK, call that method in parallel?

Comment: Sure, why not? Is there a reason why you think you couldn't. The important thing is that your code is scoped to a request/response cycle. What you can't (/shouldn't) do is start up a long lived thread and leave it running. Start up when you are triggered, do your work and return